# Issue with bad request syntax with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, bad-request

I am testing/attempting to learn flask, and flast_restful. This issue I get is:

`code 400, message Bad request syntax ('name=testitem')`

**main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

product_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
product_put_args.add_argument("name", type = str, help = "Name of the product")
product_put_args.add_argument("quantity", type = int, help = "Quantity of the item")

products = {}

class Product(Resource):
    def get(self, barcode):
        return products[barcode]

    def put(self, barcode):
        args = product_put_args.parse_args()
        return {barcode: args}

api.add_resource(Product, "/product/<int:barcode>")

if(__name__) == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

and my
**test.py**

```
import requests

base = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.put(base + "product/1", {"name": "testitem"})
print(response.json())
```

I have attempted to reform mat and change around both files to figure out what is sending the issue, I feel like it is something simple, but if you can help me, I bet this will help me and many others that are trying to start creating a rest API.

Comment: What is the output if you add `print(args['name'])` before returning in the put method of Product class in main.py

Comment: i got `{'message': "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the location information to the RequestParser by default it tries to parse values from `flask.Request.values`, and `flask.Request.json`, but in your case, the values need to be parsed from a [flask.request.form](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html). Below code fixes your error

```
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

product_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
product_put_args.add_argument("name", type = str, help = "Name of the product", location='form')
product_put_args.add_argument("quantity", type = int, help = "Quantity of the item", location='form')

products = {}

class Product(Resource):
    def get(self, barcode):
        return products[barcode]

    def put(self, barcode):
        args = product_put_args.parse_args()
        products[barcode] = args['name']
        return {barcode: args}

api.add_resource(Product, "/product/<int:barcode>")

if(__name__) == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Why did you add this line in put? products[barcode] = args['name']